# Function, which replaces consecutive white-space with a single white-space

Tags: strings, regex, swift

**Task-description**: Implement a function, which returns a string with all consecutive whites-spaces replaced as a single-space.

Example: "a[space][space][space]b[space][space][space]c" shall become "a[space]b[space]c"

**My implementation**:

```
func removeConsecutiveWhitespaces(str: String) -> String {
    return str.replacing(/\s{2,}/, with: " ")
}

print(removeConsecutiveWhitespaces(str: "a   b   c"))  // "a b c"
print(removeConsecutiveWhitespaces(str: "    a"))      // " a"
print(removeConsecutiveWhitespaces(str: "abc"))        // "abc"
```

The examples are taken from the exercise-sheet.

**Are there any issues with my implementation? Is there a better solution?**

Comment: **N.B :** In Swift, `\s` matches a space `" "`, a tab `"\t"`, a carriage return `"\r"`, a line feed `"\n"` and all the following flavors of a whitespace `"\u{00a0}\u{1680}\u{2000}\u{200a}\u{2028}\u{2029}\u{202f}\u{205f}\u{3000}"` but not a Zero Width No-Break Space `"\u{feff}"`

Comment: The `return` keyword is not needed

Comment: Printing in the console is not the proper way of running tests

Comment: To illustrate how slow Regular expressions are, take a look [at this playground,](https://swiftfiddle.com/uq7koq7anfeb3gjk5evhykotjm) which provides an alternative implementation.

Comment: @ielyamani:  Why don't you write a proper answer?

Comment: @iel Then please do not spend your scant amount of time defying the simple contribution guidelines.  If you want to review the question and share insights, you are expected to post an answer.  If you want to request clarifying info or merely post reference links, leave a comment.  Please play by the rules and role model good behavior so that other users don't get the wrong impression about what actions are okay to do despite what is clearly written in the help pages.

Comment: @mickmackusa feel free to delete extraneous comments

Comment: ...likewise @ielyamani

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts:

- You might consider defining this as a `String` extension and/or follow standard naming conventions (e.g. `removing…` rather than `remove…`):

  ```swift
  extension String {
      func removingConsecutiveWhitespaces() -> String {
          return replacing(/\s{2,}/, with: " ")
      }
  }
  ```

  (Note, `return` is not required in this case, though I include it for the sake of clarity. Either include or exclude as you see fit.)

  You would invoke that like so:

  ```swift
  let result = string.removingConsecutiveWhitespaces()
  ```

  Note, the convention of using `removing…` to return a new string is not only convention, but also affords us the ability to offer a `remove…` rendition for in-place replacements:

  ```swift
  extension String {
      func removingConsecutiveWhitespaces() -> String {
          return replacing(/\s{2,}/, with: " ")
      }

      mutating func removeConsecutiveWhitespaces() {
          replace(/\s{2,}/, with: " ")
      }
  }
  ```

  (I am not going to implement both renditions in my examples below, but the above illustrates the general pattern.)
- Note that in regex, `\s` is [defined](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression) as follows:

  > Match a white space character. White space is defined as `[\t\n\f\r\p{Z}]`.

  If that was your intent (to match not only spaces, but any white space, including tabs, newlines, etc.), that’s fine. But if you really intended to match only space characters, you might want `\p{Z}` instead of `\s`.

  ```swift
  extension String {
      func removingConsecutiveWhitespaces() -> String {
          return replacing(/\p{Z}{2,}/, with: " ")
      }
  }
  ```
- In a more subtle note, there is the question of how you want to treat non-ASCII space characters. Do you really want to replace non-ASCII space characters (e.g., such the two Japanese space characters in “日本　　中国”) with `" "`? E.g., perhaps the following might be a more friendly international rendition, which replaces any series of any space characters with whatever the first space character was:

  ```swift
  extension String {
      func removingConsecutiveWhitespaces() -> String {
          return replacing(/(\p{Zs})\p{Zs}+/) { $0.1 }
      }
  }
  ```

  (Perhaps Japanese is a poor example given the diminished utility of space characters play in that language, but the point stands, that there are different space characters, not just the ASCII SP.)

  I am going to ignore this issue for the remainder of the question, but if preserving the actual space character is important, you may have to rethink the simple `" "` search/replacement.
- At the risk of premature optimization, we should note that while regular expressions are very powerful and flexible, this comes at a significant performance cost. If you are dealing with very long strings (e.g., millions of characters), this difference can start to become observable. As ielyamani pointed out, a simple loop solution can be much faster. E.g., consider this variation on his suggestion:

  ```swift
  extension StringProtocol {
      func removingConsecutiveWhitespaces() -> String {
          var array = [Character]()
          array.reserveCapacity(count)      // if the string is very, very long, this can have a material impact on performance

          var previous: Character = "#"
          for c in self {
              if c == " ", c == previous {
                  continue
              }

              array.append(c)
              previous = c
          }
          return String(array)
      }
  }
  ```

  As an aside, note that, because I am no long constrained by [`replacing(_:maxReplacements:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/replacing(_:maxreplacements:with:)), I have defined this as an extension to `StringProtocol` (meaning that it works with [substrings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/substring/), too).

  Anyway, when processing extremely long strings with lots of matches, this rendition is 10-20 times faster (in an optimized build) than the regex alternative. It is not terribly salient, but this is an example of the unit tests I was using to measure performance:

  ```swift
  final class WhitespaceRemovalTests: XCTestCase {
      let iterations = 100_000

      func testSimple() throws {
          let string = "foo  bar"
          let result = string.removingConsecutiveWhitespaces()
          XCTAssertEqual(result, "foo bar")
      }

      func testJapanese() throws {
          let string = "日本　　中国"
          let result = string.removingConsecutiveWhitespaces()
          XCTAssertEqual(result, "日本　中国")
      }

      func testNonSpaceCharacters() throws {
          let string = "foo\t\nbar"
          let result = string.removingConsecutiveWhitespacesRegex()
          XCTAssertEqual(result, string)
      }

      func testPerformance() throws {
          let string = String(repeating: "a  ", count: iterations)
          let desiredResult = String(repeating: "a ", count: iterations)

          measure {
              let result = string.removingConsecutiveWhitespaces()
              XCTAssertEqual(result, desiredResult)
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  The [`measure`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496290-measure/) function will benchmark the performance for us. You might want to make sure that the unit tests are building an optimized/release build (which is the default configuration for a project scheme). I would also turn off parallel tests, as that can skew performance results. And, I would also suggest turning on randomization of the order of test execution and repeating it several times to confirm the results.

  Now, there are lots of algorithmic permutations we might consider, but it depends upon the definition of “better solution”. Is speed the concern? Space? Readability and maintainability?
- For the sake of completeness, there is another (too-cute-by-half) trick: You can [`split`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/split(separator:maxsplits:omittingemptysubsequences:)-6c22) (with `omittingEmptySubsequences` of `true`) and then immediately call [`joined`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/joined(separator:)-1ckod) on the resulting array:

  ```swift
  extension StringProtocol {
      func removingConsecutiveWhitespaces() -> String {
          return split(separator: " ")
              .joined(separator: " ")
      }
  }
  ```

  This retains the simplicity of the regex approach, but is much faster, though not as fast as the more algorithmic approach. Also note that this trims any leading and trailing spaces, which is apparently not be desired on the basis of your examples. But you will see this approach in the wild.